# Flexbox with iframe and scrolling div

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

I have 2 divs:
Player Div which contains bootstrap:embed-responsive (16x9 size)
Episode Hints which contains recommended videos using scroll. (the rest)

I was trying to reproduce this in jsfiddle, but didnt succeed, if you can please access this link:

```
beta.indiamea.org/#/seriale/view/Ektharajaekthirani/15669
```

For now the height is set to 475px which is not responsive comparing to the player.

What i am trying to achieve is that the second column for episode hints to take the height size of the first player.

Please help me & sorry for bad explanation, but this is my first time asking here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Hi Rostislav. Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important that you post complete questions, so that the Q&A becomes useful to others well into the future. In this case, please include all relevant code in your question. See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further guidance.

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it